# Dolphin user settings (KDE)

Tags: kde, settings, dolphin

I figured out that when I change settings in Dolphin that a file called ".directory" gets created in the folder in question to stored said settings. However, I would like to change settings for the user and not per directory. One particular setting of interest is the one to show hidden directories/files. I don't want to have to do it for each directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want *all* settings to apply to all folders:

`Configure Dolphin...` > `General` > `Behaviour` and select `Use common properties for all folders`

This is for Dolphin 4.13.3. It should be similar in KDE 5.

Comment: And where does that get stored? I'd like to have a copy on hand for whenever I format my system.

Comment: I think it's `~/.kde/share/config/dolphinrc` - probably the value `GlobalViewProps=true`

Comment: You're a bloody saint.